# codeigniter passing array data from model to controller

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm executing the following query in the get_distribuidor() function of my model:

```
public function get_distribuidor()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM distribuidor where id_distribuidor='1';");

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
      echo $row['id_distribuidor'];
      echo $row['nome_empresa'];
      echo $row['cod_postal'];
      echo $row['localidade'];
      echo $row['telefone'];
      echo $row['fax'];
      echo $row['email'];
    }


    $res = array(
        'nome_empresa' => $row['nome_empresa'],
        'morada' => $row['morada'],
        'cod_postal' => $row['cod_postal'],
        'localidade' => $row['localidade'],
        'telefone' => $row['telefone'],
        'fax' => $row['fax'],
        'email' => $row['email']
    );

    return $res;

}
```

Now, returning $res to the controller, i don't know very well how to separate the multiple fields the array result contains.

I'm using this on a function of the controller:

```
$data['nome_produto']=$this->fichas_model->set_fichas();

$teste=$this->fichas_model->get_distribuidor();

$this->load->view('produtos/ponto1',$data, $teste);
```

to write on the view something like this:

```
<input type="input" name="morada" value="<?php echo $teste['morada'];?>" /><br />
```

but it's not working, can someone point me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$teste=$this->fichas_model->get_distribuidor();
$this->load->view('produtos/ponto1',$data, $teste);
```

should be:

```
$data['teste'] = $this->fichas_model->get_distribuidor();
$this->load->view('produtos/ponto1',$data);
```

The [3rd parameter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html#footer) for `view()` is used if you want to grab the content of `view()` into a variable. To pass data to the view you need to add it as an array item of `$data`.

**For Example:**

```
$data = array(
    'title' => 'My Title',
    'heading' => 'My Heading',
    'message' => 'My Message'
);

$this->load->view('blogview', $data);
// You then access $title, $heading, $message in the view file
```

What you are doing with above edit is the following essentially:

```
$data = array(
    'teste' => $this->fichas_model->get_distribuidor()
);

$this->load->view('produtos/ponto1', $data);
// You then access $teste in the view file, 
// which will be an array so you can access $teste['morada']
```