# Pass all array elements to view from controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass an array to a view from a controller. I tried to use the code below. I know it is wrong, but cannot think of what to use. **find()** function gets all rows from table, and then i want to pass those rows as array to the view. How can i do so?

```
<?php
    class Blog extends CI_Controller{

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('blog_model');
        }

        public function index(){

             $data = $this->blog_model->find(); //which gets all entries from table
            $this->load->view('template/header');
            $this->load->view('template/content', $data);
            $this->load->view('template/footer');

        }

        public function create(){
            $this->blog_model->create();


        }

        public function delete(){


        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = $this->blog_model->find(); //which gets all entries from table
$this->load->view('template/header');
$this->load->view('template/content', $data);
$this->load->view('template/footer');
```

Should be:

```
$data = array('myvar' => $this->blog_model->find());
$this->load->view('template/header');
$this->load->view('template/content', $data);
$this->load->view('template/footer');
```

Then access it in your view with:

```
$myvar
```

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14122060/1592648) for a thorough explanation.