# Codeigniter pass array from Model to Controller

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Im trying to send an array of data from the model to the controller but when I echo on controller, I only see the first value no all the array of the values. Whats wrong?

Model:

```
        $sql = "
        SELECT car_id
        FROM cars
        WHERE price= 1";

        $res = mysql_query($sql);

        $bought_cars= array();
        while ($row_ya = mysql_fetch_object($res)) 
        {
            $bought_cars[] = $row_ya->car_id;
        }
        foreach ($bought_cars as $bought_car) 
        {
                return $bought_car;
        }
```

Controller

```
$bought_car = $this->car_model->car();

echo($bought_car);
```

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: you should use `CI` active record `db` library and `$bought_cars` is array so why are not returning whole array?

Comment: foreach ($bought_cars as $bought_car) 
        {
                return $bought_car;
        }   i think this will return you the last carid am i right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [codeigniter passing array data from model to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121978/codeigniter-passing-array-data-from-model-to-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Codeigniter's [Active Record Query](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).
In Model (recommended) :

```
$this->db->select('car_id');
$this->db->from('cars');
$this->db->where('price',1);
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Updated Without Active record (Not recommended) :

```
$sql = "
        SELECT car_id
        FROM cars
        WHERE price= 1";

        $res = mysql_query($sql);

        $bought_cars= array();
        while ($row_ya = mysql_fetch_object($res)) 
        {
            $bought_cars[] = $row_ya->car_id;
        }
        return $bought_cars;//no need to run foreach, you just have to return the array after completing your push operation.
```

Comment: It isn't possible to do it without Codeigniter's Active Record Query?

Comment: But you can do it with Active records ,so no need to use the normal ones.Just change your model function with my code and you will get the array of car_id.

Comment: But the problem is that when I try to echo on Controller, dont write all the array.

Comment: if you made changes to `return array` than you have to use `print_r($bought_car)` to print the array.

Comment: With print_r($bought_car) I got the values like this :  [0] => 232453 [1] => 212345 [2] How can I do to got them like 232453,212345?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59168/discussion-between-harshal-mahajan-and-devtreat).

Answer (score 0):

It ends in first loop returning the first value it gets that's why you get a first value while echoing on controller.Rather do this to return a whole array.

```
while ($row_ya = mysql_fetch_object($res)) 
    {
        $bought_cars[] = $row_ya->car_id;
    }
return $bought_cars;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this way like:-

```
$sql = "SELECT car_id FROM cars WHERE price= 1";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `return` in your model, which is causing the loop/function to end and only return the first value within your array. Just remove your `foreach` loop entirely and simply return `$bought_cars` within your model.

In order to show all the values of your array within your controller you'd have to loop through it.

```
foreach($bought_car as $car) {
    echo $car . '<br>';
}
```

Or, if you want to make it more readable you can use:

```
<pre><?php print_r($bought_car); ?></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use active record to achieve this:

Model

```
    $this->db-select('car_id')
    $this->db->where('price', 1);               
    $query = $this->db->get('cars'); if($query->num_rows() > 0){
         foreach ($query->result() as $row)
         {
            $data[] = $row;
         }
        return $data;
    }
```

Controller

```
    $bought_car = $this->car_model->car(); foreach($bought_car as $car) { echo $car->car_id
```

}

Remember you SELECTED only car_id so that is the only available column to echo